# How to generate files in source folder using Bazel?

Tags: java, bazel, eclipse-classpath

I'm trying to use VS Code to write Java programs which are built Bazel. Most of vs code extensions don't know about Bazel. Therefore code complete works only for the .java files understand the same folder.

I came up.with this idea of generating Eclipse's .project and .classpath out of Bazel java_* targets. I manually created these files and code completion worked perfectly.

So now the question boils down to: how can I automatically generate .project and .classpath files *in the same diretore* of BUILD file?

Comment: Is there an option for them to be in a different folder? I strongly suggest looking how IntelliJ solved it with an aspect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like they already decided not support it: https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/issues/3376

Comment: Also check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47764221/how-to-write-files-to-current-directory-instead-of-bazel-out/47872013#47872013