# Automatically copy executable after build with Bazel

Tags: c++, bazel

Suppose I have the following directory layout:

```
.../
  root/
    bin/
      sdl.dll
    src/
      main/
        main.cpp
        BUILD
      WORKSPACE
```

And a BUILD file that says:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "test",
    srcs = ["main.cpp"]
)
```

And my build command line is:

```
bazel build //main:hello-world --symlink_prefix=/
```

What do I need to add to my BUILD file such that test.exe (and test.pdb, if applicable) gets copied to bin (alongside sdl.dll)?

I looked at [this page](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/output_directories.html) and tried using `--output_base` but way more stuff than I wanted to.

P.S: In "Visual Studio" term I'm looking to change $(OutDir) or a postbuild from $(OutDir) to ..\bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with Bazel directly. Bazel does not write to your source directories for hermeticity reasons. The workaround is to use a post-build step script that is either manually run, or by using `bazel run`.

Also see: [How to write files to current directory instead of bazel-out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47764221/how-to-write-files-to-current-directory-instead-of-bazel-out/47872013#47872013).

Comment: I read about the not writing to the source directories, but the `bin` folder is a sibling to `source` so I thought I would be fine?

Comment: The output_base is essentially where all the work is done, and it doesn't write to files outside of this directory or directories that it doesn't own to prevent contamination. However, there is the `bazel-bin` symlink for convenience in the root of your workspace, where the WORKSPACE file is.

Comment: That said, there are some exceptions like the `repository_cache`, where it stores and shares cached external dependencies across workspaces.